# Laravel-Mediable - delete media together with file

Tags: php, laravel

I've been reading the Laravel-Mediable [docs](http://laravel-mediable.readthedocs.io/en/latest/media.html#deleting-media) about deleting media.

However, I'm a bit confused on how to delete a specific media, together with its file without using query builder. As per the docs,

> Note: The delete() method on the query builder will not delete the associated file. It will still purge relationships due to the cascading foreign key.

Answer (score 2):

Author of laravel-mediable here.

The reason for this is that when a mediable model's `delete()` method is called, we are able to [hook](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent#events) into that behaviour to clean up the file from the disk. However, when the `delete()` method of the query builder is called, it simply runs a `DELETE FROM ...` SQL query on the database without notifying any other part of the application.

The easiest way to delete models matching a query along with their files is to perform a select query first, then delete the models one by one.

```
$results = Media::where(...)->get();
$results->each(function($media) {
    $media->delete();
});
```

Granted, that results in N+1 queries. I will make note to add a better mass deletion method to the todo list for the next version.